# python conversion between color spaces

Tags: python, color-space

I wanted to convert from rgb to hsv but the results seem to be unexpected

Following is the code

```
   import colorsys

   print colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(144, 190, 255)
```

and it prints following

```
    (0.5, 0, 255)
```

where I was expecting it to be

```
    (215,44,100)
```

or

```
    (215,0.44,1.0)
```

any idea???

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [documentation of `colorsys`](http://docs.python.org/library/colorsys.html) explains that all colour space coordinates are floating point numbers between `0.0` and `1.0` – rescale your values accordingly to get the desired results:

```
>>> h, s, v = colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(144/255., 190/255., 255/255.)
>>> 360 * h, 100 * s, 100 * v
(215.13513513513513, 43.529411764705884, 100.0)
```